# How to convert a string into binary data (EDID) in python

Tags: python, binary, data-conversion, edid

I currently writing a EDID Script to be able to choose custom resolutions in my Fedora25

I found [this](https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator/blob/master/edid.S) assembly script to generate the different solutions. I was able to use this as a "template" and my python script works fine generating the CEA Extension Blobs. Now i want to merge the "Head" and my CEA Blobs with the help of [the Wikipedia EDID Byte Order Site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data).

But in the GitHub Skript this (end1-start1) confuses me:

```
Descriptor2:
start1:     .ascii  "Linux #0"
end1:       .byte   0x0a    /* End marker */
            .fill   12-(end1-start1), 1, 0x20 /* Padded spaces */
```

How can i do `"Linux #0" - 10`? (0x0a = 10)
When i converte "Linux #0" i get `76 105 110 117 120 32 35 48` what doesnt make sense with the 18 Byte for the Descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In assembler, the tokens at the beginning of lines refer to addresses.  `start1` is the address where the string `"Linux #0"` starts, `end1` is the address where the byte `0x0a` starts (or is located because it is a single byte).  The term `(end1-start1)` refers to the difference of the addresses.  Since the assembler places the things right after each other into the memory, this is the length of the string `"Linux #0"`, i. e. 8.

The term `12 - (end1-start1)` then is the number of padding bytes needed to fill up the thing to 12 bytes.  These are then placed behind the `.byte` `0x0a` (`.fill`ed with spaces (`0x20`)).

Comment: WOW, so thats good to know. Then i have  another Questions now: What does assembler do with the  `"Linux #0"` string? I would convert it to `76 105 110 117 120 32 35 48` and write it out in python.

Comment: An assembler creates a binary file.  This binary will contain the stuff before your source, then the ASCII characters of `"LINUX #0"`, then a byte `0x0a`, then 4 padding spaces (`0x20`), then the stuff after your source.  During assembly time (and only during that!), the address where the `"Linux #0"` is located will be accessible by the name `start1`, etc.  So if other parts of the source refer to `start1`, those occurrences will be replaced by this address.

Comment: okey, but i think you didn't got me. If assembler create binary files it needs to convert the ascii string `"Linux #0"` to "show" it binary or am i wrong?

Comment: With `.ascii` you stated to the assembler that it should treat the characters `L`, `i`, etc. as ASCII characters.  In ASCII the `L` is the number 0x4c, so the binary will contain a byte of this value, then a byte of the value 0x69 for the `i` etc.  Had you used .ebcdic (for instance, and if your assembler is capable of this encoding) the values would have been 0xd3 and 0x89.